# I am facing java.lang.reflect.InvocationOnTargetException

Tags: javafx

> My Main.java class code. I Have searched the old question and answer and already tried different solution but in vain. Please I have wasted whole day to resolve the issue. Any help please.

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("testcode.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

> testcode.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="508.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController.java">
   <children>
      <Button id="btn1" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="178.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateRandom" text="Test Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> complete stack trace of the exception

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/JavaFXDemo/bin/application/testcode.fxml:6

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainController.java
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

> Adding Class Heirarchy as well of eclipse ide.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMxgq.png)

> Controller code added.

```
package Controller;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainController {

public void generateRandom(ActionEvent event) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(rand));
}

 }
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your controller?

Comment: It looks like you didn't connect it properly

Comment: Controller code added please see.

Comment: Your controller's class name is `Controller.MainController` but in the FXML file you have `fx:id=MainController.java`. First of all, don't put the `.java` there; the value of `fx:id` is the _fully qualified class name_ not the source file. Second, even without the `.java` you are giving the wrong class name.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (package names should be lower-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your controller class has to be in the same package as the rest of your project for the FXML file to access it.
   Moving it to the application package should fix this.
2. `fx:controller= MainController.java` In your FXML controller declaration, you are supposed to put the class path so you should change this to `fx:controller=application.MainController`
3. The generate random method is called whenever the button is pressed and works with no parameters.

Comment: Done but still same error. Moved the MainController in the same package.

Comment: Done Error Resovled just added application to the following line. fx:controller=application.MainController. Thanks.

Comment: @BilalMujahid if _application.MainController_ is the solution then the code you are showing doesn't fit .. (MainController is in package Controller) - in future please be precise in your questions